# customize scrollbar (::-webkit-scrollbar) not working in version 121.0.6167.86

Tags: scrollbar

I updated chrome at today. Now my customize scrollbar all not working, please guide me resolve this issue.
This is my customize CSS

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {<br/>
  background-color: rgba(68, 102, 242, 0.15);<br/>
}<br/>

body.dark-only::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {<br/>
  background-color: rgba(41, 50, 64, 0.52);<br/>
}<br/>

::-webkit-scrollbar {<br/>
  height: 6px;<br/>
  width: 6px;<br/>
}
```

I searched google and couldn't find an answer.
Hope to get help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chrome 121, support was added for `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar-width`. If some of these properties are used, then `::-webkit-scrollbar` won't work.

Chrome 121 release notes: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-121?hl=ru#css-updates

I suggest using code like below to support custom scroll in Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  * {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: tks you so much

Comment: Yeah, they've added that logic, but in fact I cannot make 'scrollbar-color` work at all. Thanks for the workaround

Comment: here's a workaround I did: https://syntackle.com/blog/changes-to-scrollbar-styling-in-chrome-121/